# PRAW throwing Max retries exceeded with URL

Tags: praw

I'm not very experienced at praw, so I wrote a simple program that finds the top posts in a subreddit as a test:

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = 'id',
                    client_secret = 'secret',
                    user_agent = 'agent')

top = reddit.subreddit('memes').top(limit=5);

for post in top:
    print(post.title)
```

However, it always returns the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 496, in _connect_tls_proxy
    return ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 432, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 474, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 573, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.reddit.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/access_token (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\requestor.py", line 53, in request
    return self._http.request(*args, timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.reddit.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/access_token (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jlche\Desktop\Wörk\Discord bots\Reddit Entertainment Bot\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    for post in top:
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\praw\models\listing\generator.py", line 63, in __next__
    self._next_batch()
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\praw\models\listing\generator.py", line 73, in _next_batch
    self._listing = self._reddit.get(self.url, params=self.params)
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 530, in get
    return self._objectify_request(method="GET", params=params, path=path)
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 626, in _objectify_request
    self.request(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 808, in request
    return self._core.request(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 332, in request
    return self._request_with_retries(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 252, in _request_with_retries
    return self._do_retry(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 162, in _do_retry
    return self._request_with_retries(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 252, in _request_with_retries
    return self._do_retry(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 162, in _do_retry
    return self._request_with_retries(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 227, in _request_with_retries
    response, saved_exception = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 185, in _make_request
    response = self._rate_limiter.call(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\rate_limit.py", line 35, in call
    kwargs["headers"] = set_header_callback()
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\sessions.py", line 282, in _set_header_callback
    self._authorizer.refresh()
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 325, in refresh
    self._request_token(grant_type="client_credentials")
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 153, in _request_token
    response = self._authenticator._post(url, **data)
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\auth.py", line 28, in _post
    response = self._requestor.request(
  File "C:\Users\jlche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\prawcore\requestor.py", line 55, in request
    raise RequestException(exc, args, kwargs)
prawcore.exceptions.RequestException: error with request HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.reddit.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/access_token (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

I have looked at other StackOverflow quetions, but none have resolved my problem. I have ndg-httpsclient, pyopenssl and pyasn1 installed. I'm running Python 3.9 and my computer is not connected to any proxies.

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

pip install requests==2.24.0
There maybe some problems with lastest version, especially when you use VPN